# Persistant "Error reading from database" error

Tags: moodle

I'm new to Moodle 3.7!

I was trying to get it installed in the AMP stack that already comes with the Mac (except for the MySQL 8.0.12 which I installed separately). It all went okay so far, except for a few Issues I stumbled upon and got them fixed until I face this persistent "Error reading from database" error at the end of the installation process. If I'm not mistaken, I'm supposed to be greeted with my first admin screen to change my password and whatnot.

I've searched for an entire day so far only to find my efforts were in vain. I suspect it is some issue emerging from "dml_read_exception".

Thank you in advance for your anticipated support.

Comment: What issues you stumbled upon and got fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of research and digging into the code, I realized that I had erased the default prefix for database set by moodle, "mdl_". Apparently, this is important.
I'm really not very well versed with databases so not very good at its terminologies.
It would be appreciative if anyone explains how it works and why it affected my installation process. Thank you.